# Why won't the mods do anything about the user I don't like?

Tags: discussion

I am having a problem with a user; why don't the mods take care of that person and put them in their place?

Comment: A downvote? You (The DVer) do realize this is the place to discuss the working of the board and the behavior of members, among other things, right? The discussion here is not always about PF per se.

Comment: It's _perfectly_ fine for someone to write a self-answered question like this, especially if it allows them to stop repeating themselves and just link to it instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple of things:

### First

In my opinion, mods are supposed to protect the quality of the site first, and settle user disputes last.  Users should work it out amongst themselves. If conversation in the chat room doesn't work, then SILENCE is a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Also, seriously, take a break.  I recently was moving and remodeling a house and I didn't visit the site except on my phone on the bus on the way home.  It was great.  This is a wonderful site, but taking time off sure help reinvigorate my attention.

**Please remember:**

- Do not feed the trolls
- Flag it and move on
- *Down votes are a GREAT way to tell a user you disagree with them.*
- [Be nice first](http://www.wikihow.com/Be-Nice)

### Second

You don't know what the mods are saying to other users.  You don't know because it wouldn't be right for mods to talk about other users.  We are doing our best to respect and listen to everybody.

I will tell you that we take very seriously any allegation of playing favorites, and if you feel that favoritism is going on, please address it with us or use the contact link at the bottom of every page if you're not satisfied with how you, or your concerns have been addressed.

Mods are volunteers and we are imperfect; let us know how you feel.  You as much a part of the community as anybody else.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer or correct mine

Comment: Just a tiny edit. Folks contacting us aren't really going over a mod's head, they're just asking for something to be reviewed, just like anything else. In almost _all_ circumstances, it's clear why the mod took (or didn't take) an action, and we end up simply explaining it more than anything else.

Answer (score 8):

Misbehaving users are a great source of "helpful" flags which you'll eventually get badges for, so just let it all wash over you and get on with making your own positive contributions to the site.

Comment: I appreciate this.  Life gives you lemons, try to gamify the system =)